# Why does x command shows "Value can't be converted to integer" when I want to examine data including registers?

Tags: assembly, gdb, nasm

I hope someone could help me. I'm trying to examine data from variables.. it works well when I use the address memory but the error shows up when I try with registers.

I'm doing this in a x32 ubuntu VM hosted in a x64 machine.. does this make any difference?

Thank you in advance!! :D [The issue when i want to examine data including registers :c](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bqm6h.png)
[The assembly code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kk5cg.png)

Comment: `var1` is not a register, it's a memory location. So drop the `$`. Also, post the code itself, not a screenshot of it.

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax for what you are trying to do is:

```
x/xb &var1
```

That is, examine memory at location where `var1` resides.